# notify user after stored procedure is called successfully in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, notifications

Say I am working on Asp.net, there is a button on my page that will call a stored procedure(Oracle) to insert my page data into database table if I click it.

Say my page data now is stored in a datatable so that I have to loop it to assign the data to stored procedure row by row.

If the stored procedure inserted data successfully, it will return a flag such as "S".

EXP:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
//call stored procedure
}
```

if the 10 loops are all successful, I would like to let the user know that the data are inserted into database. And pls attention once clicking the button, page will be refreshed. So simply "Response.Write" won't work.

Thank you

Comment: A simple solution - maybe use an UpdatePanel ? If your stored procedures take a long time to run then you might want to decouple the process further; consider something like SignalR to push notifications

Comment: ajax? maybe that's a way to do that. the main problem is the entire page will be refreshed, even use ajax

Comment: How do you arrive at that conclusion ? If you use ajax properly, i.e. put your postback controls inside an updatepanel, or use jquery ajax, then you don't refresh the entire page ??

Comment: Like the comments above suggest, use an updatepanel or ajax. You can easily extend asp.net web forms with the ajax control toolkit https://www.devexpress.com/products/ajax-control-toolkit/